# How can I write to a file instead of an in memory byte array?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, file-transfer

At the moment I have this code, which recieves information over the network, stores it into an in-memory byte array, and then writes it out via a FileStream.

```
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());

  // first message is file size
         string cmdFileSize = reader.ReadLine();

  // first message is filename
        string cmdFileName = reader.ReadLine();

        int length = Convert.ToInt32(cmdFileSize);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
        int received = 0;
        int read = 0;
        int size = 1024;
        int remaining = 0;


   while (received < length)
        {
            remaining = length - received;
            if (remaining < size)
            {
                size = remaining;
            }

            read = tcpClient.GetStream().Read(buffer, received, size);
            received += read;
            if (read < size)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

After this, "buffer" is written to a file via FileStream.  This works well, but when I have files that are large, obviously that amount of memory gets taken up.  I'd like to stream these files directly to disk, instead of writing to ram and then rewriting them to the hard drive.

How could I do this?

Comment: have you looked at the [TcpClient.GetStream Method on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: check this out to if you want to write to a file instead http://www.hostprojects.net/snippets/cs/76/client-server-file-transfer-example

Comment: @MethodMan Yes, you can use StreamReader to do that but I think underlying code may anyway end up using buffer.

Comment: you can try something like this to insure that for the larger files you can multiply the `1024` size something like this 
`byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];`

Comment: I use a method that does something similar when reading from a ResponseStream for example.. would you like to see the Method that I am using you would just need to alter it slightly to work for your use case..

Comment: What OP is looking for is a way to write data directly in file instead of any buffer which I doubt is possible

Comment: @MethodMan thats actually the exact code I'm referencing haha.  Surely, there must be a way?  I know its wildly different, but if you copy a file over a SMB share the file is written to the drive without first storing it in memory

Comment: @viru I'd be happy using a buffer, if the buffer could be smaller (happy to use a 10mb buffer for instance, and have the buffer somehow "append" to  the file once the 10mb is full).

Comment: @LewisCianci i have a method that could work for what you are doing or trying to do.. would you like to see the Method I created to do something similar..??

Comment: @MethodMan I'd love to, please :)

Comment: @LewisCianci where I have `request  and Response` just replace that part with your `StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());` does that make sense..?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use StreamWriter to stream the contents out to the file as they come in?

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());

// first message is file size
string cmdFileSize = reader.ReadLine();

// first message is filename
string cmdFileName = reader.ReadLine();

int length = Convert.ToInt32(cmdFileSize);
byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
int received = 0;
int read = 0;
int size = 1024;
int remaining = 0;

using (FileStream writer = File.OpenWrite("outfile.dat"))
{
    while (received < length)
    {
        remaining = length - received;
        if (remaining < size)
        {
            size = remaining;
        }

        read = tcpClient.GetStream().Read(buffer, 0, size);
        received += read;
        writer.Write(buffer, 0, size);

        if (read < size)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I think you have a bug in your code. I assume that you are using `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient` which returns a `NetworkStream` object when you call `GetStream()`. In that case, the second argument to the `Read` method should probably always be 0. That argument indicates where in the `buffer` variable to start writing the data read from the network. If you don't use 0, you are likely to get array out of bounds exceptions. Check out the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read(v=vs.110).aspx) for the `Stream.Read` method.

Comment: This is probably on the outer limits of my understanding (meaning, this is starting to make my brain smoke) but are you saying that the offset of getstream should always be zero, because i'll always want *everything* from getstream? That makes sense to me. Or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: Basically I'm just saying it should be read = tcpClient.GetStream().Read(buffer, 0, size);

Comment: Can I switch File.CreateText for new StreamWriter(destinationfile)? I won't always be writing text :) I will probably be writing binary most of the time.

Comment: You can use FileStream, which works the same was as the NetworkStream. I updated the answer to reflect that (and fix the bug I mentioned).

Comment: Thanks.  In practice, this code operates very slowly... on loopback it transmits about a megabyte every minute.  I can't quite figure it out :(

Comment: Is your network connection slow? You can try replacing the network stream with a stream from a file on your local box. If it works much faster with the file then it's probably the network connection.

Comment: Well it's on loop back, shouldn't that be very very fast?

Comment: I suppose so but it could be whatever is generating the network data stream that is running slowly. Replacing it with a file as I suggested above might tell you that. Other than that, I can't tell without having your code.

Comment: Yeah.  Essentially all I'm trying to do is iterate through a series of files and send them from a client to a server. Both client and server are wrapped up in the same exe, but the server is running on a different thread.  I'd love an example or something of how someone else got this to work, I'm sure its a common enough problem..